# python cannot run selenium tests in firefox but pytest can

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, webdriver, pytest

I'm using pytest with selenium. I have a simple setup:

`browser = webdriver.Firefox()`

when running the test file with `py.test test_foo.py`
The firefox browser launched correctly, got the url and executed the test with no problem.

Then i created another python file testsuite1.py which contains
`pytest.main('py.test test_foo.py')`

I ran `python testsuite1.py`, it opens the Firefox browser but failed to get the URL and finish the test. The error that it failed on:

`WebDriverException: Message: The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.`

I googled many different posts on this issue and I couldn't find any solutions. I've updated to Selenium 2.47.1, using Firefox 40. I don't understand why it would work with py.test command and not pytest.main within python.

Any ideas?

Comment: I stumbled upon the same thing. Did you ever figure out a solution?

Comment: unfortunately i haven't found a solution yet. From most of the research, it all points to the version of FF being incompatible, I have installed and tried different versions and no avail.